# Difficulty solving integral to model motion of particle

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I am working on a project modeling the motion of a particle given certain constants, a,c,n, and $\theta$. I am not sure how to approach it and Wolfram Alpha was unable to solve it

The integral is as follows

$$
\int\tan\left(\,\arcsin\left(\,\exp\left(\,-ac\,\mathrm{e}^{nx} -
\frac{c^{2}}{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{2nx}\,\right)\,\right) + \theta\,\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

The constants have the following possible ranges of values:
$$a > 0$$
$$c < 0$$
$$ 0 < n < 1$$
$$ 0 < \theta < \pi$$

The integral should have some solution, as I am fairly certain that it is physically meaningful

To add some context: This integral is to solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ given initial state $y = 0$

The ultimate goal is to find an equation for $\theta$ in terms of y, x, and the other constants

**Edit**: Due to the complexity of the integral, I have been for looking for a way to express the integrand as $f(\theta) * f(u)$ as opposed to $f(u + \theta)$ (where u is the arcsin function). If I could find a way to do that, the integral would simplify to $f(\theta) * \int f(u) dx$.

Then $y = f(\theta) * \int_{x_0}^{x_f} f(u) dx$ and I could find theta via $\theta = f^{-1}(\frac{y}{\int_{x_0}^{x_f} f(u) dx})$ since a computer could estimate the definite integral

Unfortunately, I have played quite a bit with the trig Identities and I don't know if there is a way to simplify  $tan(u + \theta)$ to any two factors $f(\theta) * f(u)$

Comment: The integral does have a solution, since the integrand is continuous on its domain. This does not imply that it's "elementarily" expressible. It probably is not, since Wolfram is typically able to solve integrals much better than humans can.

Comment: I presume that the integral is with respect to $x$?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my post to make that clear

Comment: What's the differential equation that you're trying to solve?

Comment: It's just $\frac{dy}{dx} = \tan\left(\,\arcsin\left(\,\exp\left(\,ac\,\mathrm{e}^{nx} +
\frac{c^{2}}{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{2nx}\,\right)\,\right) + \theta\,\right)$

Comment: The ultimate goal is to find an equation for $\theta$ in terms of y and the other constants